# Firebase realtime database not returning all values on Android debug APK version

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app works fine when I install from Android studio, but when using the debug APK version, Firebase for some reason won't download all the values from the real time database. I have no idea why it only happens on the APK version.

To get an idea of what's not working, I have listener as follows:

```
ValueEventListener questionListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        GenericTypeIndicator<List<Question>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<Question>>() {};
            mQuestions = (ArrayList<Question>) dataSnapshot.getValue(t);

    ...

mDatabase.child("surveys").child("surveyName").child("questions").addValueEventListener(questionListener);
```

The problem is that inside a question there are question options and each option has several parameters. When I install the app via Android Studio it receives all the parameters and it works fine. However when I build the debug APK and install it, then one of the parameters is missing (on all questions). What's even weirder is that it only seems to happen for one field. That field used to be a Boolean but I changed it to a String just to see if it would make any difference. Sadly it still has the same problem.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this might be happening or where I can even look?

Every question option in the database has this field set. Why won't it download it when using the APK version? Is it a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear how your "debug APK" and version "installed from Android Studio" differ.  When you install and run from AS, is that a release version or build flavor different from your "debug APK"?

Comment: I'm running the debug built variant from AS. There's no release version. I'm using the debug key for auth.

Comment: @michael Exactly I stuck in your situation and it is really strange, others will not understand until they face it.

Comment: Yeah I think maybe it's a bug. If it's not fixed in a few weeks when I need to test this situation again I might submit my first firebase bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like I solved my own question. I don't see mention of it on the documentation page https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data but it really should say something.

It seems to be a requirement of Firebase to have a getter for each parameter with the exact spelling of "get< parameter name >". If you have something like "public Boolean HasExtraInput" it won't work.

I tested "get< parameter name >" and then "goingToGet< parameter name >". The first one works and the second one fails with everything else being identical. And the method isn't even being used according to Android Studio so it can only be Firebase.

Interestingly it works when running from Android Studio regardless, but when using the APK it falls apart with different spelling. Not sure why that is, but at least I know how to make it work.